# Can't access label

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm a total beginner at iPhone development so I have a little question:

This is my viewcontroller.m

```
//
//  ViewController.m
//  Conversie talstelsels
//
//  Created by Stijn Hoste on 16/11/12.
//  Copyright (c) 2012 Stijn Hoste. All rights reserved.
//

#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@synthesize lblOct;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)txtGetal:(id)sender {

  lblOct.text = @"derp";


}
@end
```

This is my viewcontroller.h

```
//
//  ViewController.h
//  Conversie talstelsels
//
//  Created by Stijn Hoste on 16/11/12.
//  Copyright (c) 2012 Stijn Hoste. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
- (IBAction)txtGetal:(id)sender;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lblDec;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lblOct;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lblHex;

@end
```

So when I try to do this:  @synthesize lblOct;
It gives me the following error: illegal interface qualifier
When I try to do this: lblOct.text = @"derp";
It gives me this error: use of undeclared identifier 'lblOct', did you mean '_lblOct'?

Can somebody help me with this probably easy problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're not supposed to `@synthesize` a property in the interface - move that into the implementation.

Comment: Move the `@synthesize` into the `@implementation`.

Comment: When you don't have an `@synthesize`, the latest Xcode will supply one, but it will associate your "xxxx" property with instance variable "_xxxx".  (Whereas `@synthesize xxxx;` associates property "xxxx" with instance variable "xxxx".)  That explains your second error message.

Comment: Remove that @interface section from the .m file.

Comment: @ott--There's nothing wrong with the `@interface` section in the .m, and the later versions of Xcode supply it by default when you create a new class.  It's just that the `@synthesize` statements don't belong there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use

```
self.lblOct.text = @"text";
// or
_lblOct.text = @"text";
```

In `Xcode` 4.4(LLVM 4.0 Compiler) or newer version if you don't add `@synthesize` the Xcode will add a default one like

```
@synthesize variable = _variable;
```

Comment: Thank you for all the answers! This one solved my problem. Happy coding!

Comment: @StijnHoste So, could you Accept my answer as this solved your problem? Thanks! I like the feeling of my answer to be up voted.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `self.lblOct = @"text";`

Also, with new XCode, you don't need to use `@synthesize` anymore, so just omit it.